# java.lang.ArrayIndexOutOfBoundsException error in nested if statements

Tags: java, loops, arrays

```
    }
```

I have an input.txt file, i want call that from console. This file includes whitespaces and quotes. I write this code but it give me the error. Where is my fault in this code, guys?

Also, `if (chars[i]=='"'){
                j = i ;
                i++ ;
                while (chars[i] != '"'){
                    i++;
                }
                System.out.println(str.substring(j,i));
            }`
because of the error, the print does not work.

Comment: You are making a basic mistake here. Arrays in java start at index 0, so even thought you have a length of N, the maximum array index is N-1.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What happens if the last character of the string is ' '?

Look at the case of the string `" "` (single space)

```
while(i < chars.length) // i == 0
  chars[0] == ' ' // true;
  i++; // i = 1 (past array end)
  if (chars[1] == '"') // you've accessed past the end of the array and you get the exception
```

Comment: The exception part solved with this way. But my code doesn't work with quotes. It does not seperate quotes, only whitespace. How can I solve this?

Comment: What are you trying to achieve here? If you can, use a builtin like `String replaced = str.replaceAll("[ \"\']", "")` to remove all spaces, single and double quotes from the string.

Comment: I want to split all words. In input.txt, i have to seperate these words with spaces and quotes. For example; a b c "d e"

Comment: use `String[] res = str.split("[ \'\"]");` which splits a string into an array of strings.

Comment: I know that split function. This parsing only whitespace again

Answer (score 1):

```
while(i < chars.length)
```

and

```
i++ ;
```

will get you into trouble at

```
if (chars[i]=='"'){
```

Answer (score 0):

I think you should check "i" variable always after "i++" operation - checking it in most outside while isn't enough, you can go out the array size